# MYSQL: Exclude a product from a result based on category when several exist

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables of data. One is products and the other is a taxinomy table of categories they are in. I cannot figure out how to make an exclusion work and cover all instances in the taxonomy table.

Table Products

```
ID | Name
1  | Apples
2  | Oranges
3  | Potatoes
4  | Rosemary
```

Table Category

```
TaxID | ID | CategoryID
1     | 1  | 10
2     | 2  | 10
3     | 1  | 20
4     | 2  | 20
5     | 3  | 20
6     | 3  | 30
7     | 4  | 40
```

Now if I request this:

```
SELECT p.ID, Name, categoryID FROM Products p JOIN Category c ON p.ID = c.ID WHERE CategoryID != 30 AND CategoryID != 40 GROUP BY p.ID
```

I Get:

```
ID | Name     | CategoryID
1  | Apples   | 10
2  | Oranges  | 10
3  | Potatoes | 20
```

What I wanted was just the Apples and the Oranges and to have Potatoes not show up because they are also included in CategoryID 30. It excludes the Rosemary, but on the Potatoes it includes it because it has another category in the taxonomy table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code should be faster:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, c.categoryID, c2.ID 
FROM Products p JOIN Category c ON p.ID = c.ID 
LEFT JOIN Category c2 ON (c2.ID = c.ID AND c2.CategoryID IN (30,40))
WHERE c2.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Here is the sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d7354/12

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
SELECT p.ID, Name, categoryID
FROM Products p JOIN Category c
    ON p.ID = c.ID
WHERE p.ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM Category
    WHERE CategoryID IN (30, 40)
)
GROUP BY p.ID
```